# Excel VBA getElementsByTagName

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i'm trying to get a complex (ugly) nested table with no id but with a class name = "tableselect" then read all tr's and td's

the only quick and unique way to find the table - it is within a div tag, then a center tag.

this is the html structure.

```
    <div align="center">
    <center>
      <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' class="tableselect">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        ...
      </table>
    </center>
    </div>
```

the .getElementsByTagName("center").getElementsByTagName("table") does not work

also

.getElementsByClassName("tableselect").getElementsByTagName("tr") does not work

using excel 2016

Comment: You need to qualify which element in the collection you want returned. E.g. `set Elements = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("tableselect")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")` should give you a collection you can iterate over to each each `Tr`

Comment: getting a different error now, but is related to something else...